# Static Variable bound to textblock not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static, textblock

I'm using a textblock with a binding to a variable in a static class.
If the variable is set initially within the class, the text is updated.
But when the variable changes within a method the bound textblock text does not change.

I set the value initialy  to "initial text" and afterwards, I try to change it within a method. But the text never changes, even if i see it changes in the debugger.

I added a textblock with a binding to a static variable:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:InfoBanner.InfoBannerText}"/>
```

In the code, I implemented the following class:

```
public static class InfoBanner
{
    static InfoBanner()
    {
        infoBannerText = "initial text";
    }

    public static void showMessage(Window window)
    {
        infoBannerText = "changed text";
        Storyboard sb = window.FindResource("storyInfoBanner") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
    }

    public static string infoBannerText;

    public static String InfoBannerText
    {
        get { return infoBannerText; }
        set {
            infoBannerText = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, FilterStringPropertyEventArgs);
        }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs FilterStringPropertyEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(InfoBannerText));
        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

}
```

What I expected was, that the text updates every time I call the method showMessage.
But the text keeps the value "initial text"

Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Best regrads
hafisch

Comment: You have to set the property, not its backing field: `InfoBannerText = "changed text";` As a note, `FilterStringPropertyEventArgs` seems to be an odd name here. You would typically not store the event args as a *public* static member at all. Better just call `StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(InfoBannerText)));`

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you must update the property - not its backing field - by calling

```
InfoBannerText = "changed text";
```

you have to use a `Binding` for the Text property, instead of just an assignment:

```
Text="{Binding Path=(local:InfoBanner.InfoBannerText)}"
```

Comment: The solution was so close! It works. Thanjs a lot for your support.